# How to reuse a component develop in F# and Feliz in a different React application?

Tags: reactjs, f#, fable-f#

I am new to F# and I have built a simple checkbox control using F# and Fable.

I would like to publish this component as a npm package and reuse the component in a separate React application.

My question: is there a way to generate a npm package with just the JavaScript for the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you might reuse a Fable component:

1. For F# consumers, you can distribute a Fable compatible library via Nuget
2. For JavaScript consumers, you can distribute a JS library via NPM

It sounds like you want (2), which is fairly straight forward.

If you haven't done so already, create a .NET tool manifest and install Fable:

```bash
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install fable
```

Suppose you have an `fsproj` with this Fable component in `CheckBox.fs`:

```ml
module Components

open Feliz

[<ReactComponent>]
let CheckBox (initialState : bool) =
  let isChecked, setChecked = React.useState initialState

  Html.input
    [
      prop.type'.checkbox
      prop.value isChecked
      prop.onChange setChecked
    ]
```

Run Fable on this project:

```bash
dotnet fable .
```

Now you have JavaScript files alongside the F# files.

For example, `CheckBox.fs.js`:

```js
import { Feliz_React__React_useState_Static_1505 } from "./fable_modules/Feliz.2.3.0/React.fs.js";
import { createElement } from "react";

export function CheckBox(initialState) {
    const patternInput = Feliz_React__React_useState_Static_1505(initialState);
    return createElement("input", {
        type: "checkbox",
        value: patternInput[0],
        onChange: (ev) => {
            patternInput[1](ev.target.checked);
        },
    });
}
```

This is pure JavaScript, so you can bundle it using any standard JavaScript tool.

Don't forget to include the `fable_modules` folder.